# Unable to open HDF5 files in Python

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to upload a dataset from HDF5 into Python with the following code:

```
data = h5py.File('data.h5', 'r')
```

Whenever I do this, I keep getting the error

```
Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'data.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

I've done this with other datasets and this error keeps occurring. I was able to successfully upload only one dataset previously, but I cannot upload other datasets. The files are in my downloads. What is exactly causing this problem?

Comment: But is 'downloads' the current directory, or on the Python path?  Most likely it can't open the file because it isn't looking in the right place.  That's a basic Python issue, not specific to `h5py`

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the path you're in. It looks like that file isn't in your workspace as indicated by `error message = 'No such file or directory'`. Make sure that the file is in that folder you're running your script from, or provide an absolute path to it. If you're using Notebooks, use the `%ls` command to list all files in that working directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS code, then ensure that you are running python in the same directory (folder) as the `data.h5` file.

I was also having this issue. So I tried to `cd` into that directory and the file gets loaded.

Thanks.